# Vertica Export configuration

Tags: vertica

I have a DEV Vertica database and need to create a new TST Vertica database.
During the past few months both administrators and users have had pretty-much wide open access to do what ever was needed to get things working. Thus, the internal Vertica configuration/metadata is not well tracked nor understood.
Im looking for a way to export all the internal configuration details and metadata needed to 1) Document what the current configuration is, and 2) Deploy that configuration to a new TST Vertica database. 
Some of the things I am looking for are:

1. ACCESS/Authentication/LDAP config
2. Profiles/Resource/Roles/Users/Options
3. Object DDL, Flex tables, Schemas, Sequences
4. Anything else metadata related to be able to
   document/reproduce  the configuration.

Comment: Relevant but probably not a complete solution: https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/CopyExportData/CopyingAndExportingData.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can use Vertica's `vbr` utility with `copycluster` task to copy an entire database to another cluster. This copies **everything**, including the data.
See [Copying the Database to Another Cluster](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BackupRestore/CopyingTheDatabaseToAnotherCluster.htm?tocpath=Administrator%27s%20Guide%7CBacking%20Up%20and%20Restoring%20the%20Database%7C_____29)

Alternately, you can use the [EXPORT_CATALOG](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/EXPORT_CATALOG.htm) function. But it's limited to physical schema only, it doesn't export configurations like users, resource pools, LDAP etc.